# How to effectively assign sizes to datatypes in sql?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sqldatatypes

I'm designing an `Employee` schema in `PostgreSQL` and I have few doubts regarding the sizes of datatypes. For example, in the `Address` table for  `country` column I gave 48 keeping full-form of USSR in mind, so is it fine? for `pin code` 10 Is fine or I have to give 8?

Similarly, for columns like `company id` and `employee id` can I give `Big int` or `Int` is fine?

Also, can I use `small int` for `project members` column since the number may not be big ?

Where is a `Small Int` datatype is actually used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do some `data profiling` to answer these questions. It will be difficult to answer these questions without talking to the business and looking at the data. 
One of the outputs of a `data profiling` task is the suggestion on the data types, length, occurrence of null values in addition to other information. Ofcourse, this will depend on your sample data. 
`Company id` and `employee id` will depend if they are auto incremented numbers of are business keys. 
`Small Int` datatype as the name suggests is used when you don't expect too many distinct or large values of that field - an example will be identity field for a reference/lookup table (ex. `GenderID` = 1 for `Gender` = 'Male', `GenderID` = 2 for `Gender` = 'Female' and `GenderID` = 3 for `Gender` = 'Other').

Comment: Thank you for replying, I came to know about new word 'data profiling' and understood when actually 'small int'  is used.

Comment: Note that in Postgres you can also use an ENUM for things like a gender field. Also, I recommend making your field names all lower-case with no spaces; that way you don't have to quote them.

When it comes to specifying lengths on varchar, I'm not much of a fan other than as a safety measure (just to ensure you can't end up with 1GB in your fields if the app does something dumb). If you really care about stuff like that, you should also be ensuring there's no leading or trailing spaces, and possibly other things.